# Items using CardLayout and RecyclerView not displaying correctly

Tags: android

I am currently following this tutorial : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

I am trying to list a number of Cards to the Recycler View however when for some reason after following the tutorial and supplied code it looks like there is only one card and all the contents are in one card. See image :

[image]

All the objects defined in the initData method show up but as I mentioned it seems like all these objects are added to just one card? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**quiz_item_ui.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_age"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/person_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**QuizItemAdapter.java**

```
    public class QuizItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizItemAdapter.QuizItemViewHolder>
{

    public static class QuizItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        TextView personAge;
        ImageView personPhoto;

        QuizItemViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            personPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);

        }
    }
    List<QuizItem> items;

    QuizItemAdapter(List<QuizItem> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public QuizItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quiz_item_ui,viewGroup,false);
        QuizItemViewHolder qi = new QuizItemViewHolder(v);
        return qi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(QuizItemViewHolder quizItemViewHolder, int i)
    {
        quizItemViewHolder.personName.setText(items.get(i).name);
        quizItemViewHolder.personAge.setText(items.get(i).age);
        quizItemViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(items.get(i).photoId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private List<QuizItem> qItems;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initData();
        initAdapter();
    }
    private void initData()
    {
        qItems = new ArrayList<>();
        qItems.add(new QuizItem("Emma Wilson","23 years old",R.drawable.ic_location));
        qItems.add(new QuizItem("Emma Wilson","23 years old",R.drawable.ic_location));
        qItems.add(new QuizItem("Emma Wilson","23 years old",R.drawable.ic_location));

    }

    private void initAdapter()
    {
        QuizItemAdapter a = new QuizItemAdapter(qItems);
        rv.setAdapter(a);
    }


}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Why you use CardView Height match_parent ? use Height as Wrap_content

Comment: Oops, that was supposed to be "wrap_content"! That was one of the issues, although the contents do not spit out into their individual card views

Comment: Can you show me Image now

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I updated the screenshot to show what it looks like now :D

Comment: I use Picasso for show picture in CardView I m Kotlin Android Developer Don't know much About Java So try using Picasso for Images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cards are there - you can spot tiny triangle shadows between them on the sides. The shadow needs some space to draw itself. You need to remove padding from the main layout and add some margin to card's layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"    // remove this padding
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
```

And

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"    // add margin here
    android:id="@+id/cv"/>
```

Comment: Outstanding, not sure how I missed this, exactly what I was looking for!